# What are __asm_rep_movsb_memcpy() and __asm_rep_stosb_memset() and the like?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, decompiling

When decompiling an x86 PE executable to C code using RetDec I see lots of function calls to `__asm_rep_stosb_memset()` and `__asm_rep_movsb_memcpy()` but those aren't defined anywhere. Are those identical to `memset()` and `memcpy()` from the C runtime? If they are, why doesn't RetDec simply use `memset()` and `memcpy()`?

Also, I'm wondering what statements like this do:

```
char v3 = __asm_in(513); // 0x4010a1
```

The generated C code is full of statements like this but `__asm_in` isn't defined anywhere so I have no idea what it actually does.

So could anybody explain what these `__asm` calls are all about?

Comment: `__asm_rep_stosb_memset` *may* be how the decompiler translated a sequence of instructions of the form `mov eax, ... / mov ecx, ... / stosb` which are a way to set a memory region to a specific value. This could be an inlined call to `memcpy` or some work done by the compiler for initializing objects/vars or a `for` from the source. Ditto for `__asm_rep_movsb_memcpy`. The `__asm_in` is a mystery, but you cal look a what instructions are at `0x4010a1` and post them or see where the value 513 comes from.

Comment: When I use IDA to look what's at `0x4010a1` I see this code: `loc_4010A1: in al, dx` `test bl, al` `jz short loc_4010AA` along with some comments of `Game I/O port` and that the bits 0-3 contain coordinates and bits 4-7 buttons and triggers. So I guess this reads the state of a game controller or something? But it's strange because it's a Windows program and I wouldn't expect it to access the hardware directly.

Comment: After some research I found that `513` is indeed the game port address (0x201). But why the strange `__asm_in` statement? Why doesn't it just do `char v3 = *((char *) 0x201));` to read from the game port?

Comment: Wow, I just ruled out the `in` instruction since it's privileged. `in` read from the IO address space, which is different from the memory space. Good finding, BTW!